# How to pick out all input children from a form tree in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm dealing with forms using Javascript for validation. For the sake of organizing and formatting the inputs, I need to use `div`, `table`, `span`, etc. That causes a problem for me when I'm trying to get all the form information. Right now, I have a script that loops through all children of the parent (form), and does things accordingly. Unfortunately, because those pesky `span`, `div`, `table`, `tr`, and `td` elements are all involved now, I can't get to the inputs using `.childNodes`. How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "elements" property of a form element gives a list of all inputs (etc.) in the form. That is,

```
var form = document.forms[0]; // or getElementById() ..
var elements = form.elements;
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
  var element = elements[i];
  // do something with form element
}
```

It doesn't matter how many non-form wrapper elements are in the form, so this works regardless of your HTML markup. *edit* — this also works in old browsers that don't support the "querySelector" APIs.

Comment: Ideally that works, however I'm getting a strange result. All checkboxes are being sent as "on" even if they are not checked...

Answer (score 0):

User the `:input` selector: (http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery: `$('#parentElement').find('input')`

Comment: `querySelector('#parentElement').querySelectorAll('input')`

Comment: Yes, true :)  However the "elements" property already has all the elements (and includes `<select>` and `<textarea>` elements too).

Answer (score 0):

Use `querySelectorAll`:

```
document.querySelector('#parentElement').querySelectorAll('input')
```

Documentation: [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector), [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll).

Both functions can be run on elements as well. Browser compatibility is in the docs.